# Physical Naming Strategy getting registered but not triggering while persistence

Tags: java, hibernate

---

Physical Naming Strategy getting registered but not getting triggered during persistence.

I am trying to configure PhysicalNaming Strategy for my dropwizard hibernate bundle

```
public abstract class CustomHibernateBundle<T extends io.dropwizard.Configuration> extends ScanningHibernateBundle<T> {

protected CustomHibernateBundle(String pckg) {
    this(pckg, new SessionFactoryFactory());
}

protected CustomHibernateBundle(String pckg, SessionFactoryFactory sessionFactoryFactory) {
    this(new String[]{pckg}, sessionFactoryFactory);
}

protected CustomHibernateBundle(String[] pckgs, SessionFactoryFactory sessionFactoryFactory) {
    super(pckgs, sessionFactoryFactory);
}

public void configure(Configuration configuration) {
    super.configure(configuration);
    configuration.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new CustomNamingStrategy());
}
}



public class CustomNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy {
private String tableName(Identifier identifier) {
 if (identifier == null)
        return null;
    String newName = identifier.getText();
    String customID = (String) MDC.get("CUSTOM-ID");
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(customID) && taint.equalsIgnoreCase("custom_id"))
        newName = newName + "_custom";
    return newName;
}

@Override
public Identifier toPhysicalCatalogName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
    return identifier;
}

@Override
public Identifier toPhysicalSchemaName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
    return identifier;
}

@Override
public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
    return jdbcEnvironment.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier(tableName(identifier));
}

@Override
public Identifier toPhysicalSequenceName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
    return identifier;
}

@Override
public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
    return identifier;
}
}
```

While bootup the naming strategy class is getting registered correctly. But when I try to persist, the actual naming strategy is not kicking in.

I have also tried using

```
hibernate.naming.physical_strategy: com.someorg.CustomStrategy
```

in my YAML file but to no use.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was calling the method on the configuration (as opposed to inserting the property),

`configuration.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new ReallyCoolNamingStrategy());`

as well as the property:

`hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers: true`

For a DropWizard + Hibernate web server:

1. Follow the setup instructions for DropWizard

   - https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.13/docs/manual/hibernate.html
2. Put the needed settings in your configuration:

   - In this snippet I've added the naming strategy.
   - For PostgreSQL I have the `globally quoted identifiers` as `false`

```
database:
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mule?currentSchema=public
  user: mule-admin
  password:
  properties:
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
    hibernate.physical_naming_strategy: net.sf.zoftwhere.hibernate.SnakeCaseNamingStrategy
    hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers: false
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
    hibernate.show_sql: false
    hibernate.format_sql: false
```

3. Update the initialization of your Hibernate Bundle:

   - Here the stored property is used for hard-coded strategies.

```
  public static <T extends DatabaseConfiguration> HibernateBundle<T> getHibernateBundle() {
    return new HibernateBundle<>(AbstractEntity.class, persistenceEntities()) {
      @Override
      public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(T configuration) {
        return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
      }

      @Override
      protected void configure(org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration) {
        final String namingStrategy = configuration.getProperty("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy");

        if (SnakeCaseNamingStrategy.class.getName().equals(namingStrategy)) {
          configuration.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy());
        } else if (MacroCaseNamingStrategy.class.getName().equals(namingStrategy)) {
          configuration.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new MacroCaseNamingStrategy());
        }
      }
    };
  }

  public static Class<?>[] persistenceEntities() {
    return new Class<?>[]{
        Account.class,
        AccessToken.class,
        ShellSession.class,
    };
  }
```

4. Double check your Strategy:

   - Ensure to return nulls for nulls.
   - Ensure to pass the `isQuoted` parameter.

```
...

  @Override
  public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(final Identifier identifier, final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnv) {
    return convertToSnakeCase(identifier);
  }

  protected Identifier convertToSnakeCase(final Identifier identifier) {
    if (identifier == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return Identifier.toIdentifier(snakeCase(identifier.getText()), identifier.isQuoted());
  }

  protected String snakeCase(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1_$2")
        .replaceAll("([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])", "$1_$2")
        .toLowerCase();
  }

...
```

Hope this helps.

`DropWizard 1.3.13` `Hibernate 5.4.3.Final` `Java 11.0.2 (Oracle)`